# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Tags: python, svm, prediction, predict

This is my code.

```
def _asarray_tuplesafe(values, dtype=None):
    from pandas.core.index import Index

    if not (isinstance(values, (list, tuple)) or hasattr(values, '__array__')):
        values = list(values)
    elif isinstance(values, Index):
        return values.values
```

Im getting following error

```
  line 379, in _asarray_tuplesafe
    values = list(values)

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

can someone please suggest a solution for this?

Comment: You are probably passing a function into this code as `value`. difficult to say. try `print(type(values))` -it is not a list-able type but a function. Error tells you as much.

Comment: Show how you're calling the function when you get the error.

Comment: i think some paranthesis is missing here! If so suggest where it should be.

Comment: how to use print(type(values)) here instead of values